# The object does not support the property or method EOF

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have 3 pages:

my DB-class

```
<!--#include virtual="/res/adovbs.inc"-->
<%
    Class classDB
        'Declarations
        Private SQL
        Private RS
        Private Conn

        'Class Initialization
        Private Sub Class_Initialize()
            Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            Conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=x"
            Call Conn.Open          
        End Sub

        'Terminate Class
        Private Sub Class_Terminate()           
            If IsObject(RS) Then 
                If RS.State = 1 Then
                    RS.Close()
                End If
            End If 
            
            If Conn.State = 1 Then
                Conn.Close()
            End If          
        End Sub

        Public Function GetRS(SQL)
            Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)

            GetRS = RS
        End Function


        Public Function ExecuteSQL(SQL)
            Conn.Execute(SQL)
        End Function
    End Class
%>
```

And my "functions":

```
<!--#include virtual="/res/classDB.asp"-->
<%
    'GET PAGED MEMBERS
    Function GetMembers(page)
        If Not IsNumeric(page) Or page = "" Then page = 1

        Dim db : Set db = new classDB
        
        Set GetMembers = db.GetRS("SELECT * FROM member")
    End Function
.....
```

And in my page:

```
<%
     Dim members : Set members = GetMembers(1)
                
     If Not members.EOF Then
          Do Until members.EOF
%>
```

I get Error:

The object does not support the property or method 'EOF'

What might be wrong here? An Object was returned to the page. But I guess it has no properties or entries.... Impossible to debug.

**EDIT**:

```
Function GetMembers(page)
    If Not IsNumeric(page) Or page = "" Then page = 1
    Dim rs
    Dim m : Set m = new classDB     
    
    Set rs = m.GetRS("SELECT * FROM member")

    Response.Write(rs("email"))

    Set GetMembers = rs
End Function
```

It prints out the email for the "member".... but it doesn't work on the "next" page with the loop.

It's it returning the recordset to the page?

```
<%
   Dim m : Set m = GetMembers(1)

   If Not m.EOF Then
       Do Until m.EOF
%>
```

Is not working..... what to do?

**EDIT**

I changed to:

```
Public Function GetRS(SQL)
    Dim RS : Set RS = m_Conn.Execute(SQL)
    Set GetRS = RS
End Function
```

Now I get error:
"The action is not allowed when the object is closed"

Google translated :)

I have the open in the Class_Initialize.... why?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `Set` when returning a value via the function name, but my vbscript is more than a little rusty.

Comment: One step closer :) ty guys :) EDIT: still issues... on code

Comment: I'm pretty sure if a function is returning an object reference `Set` is required before the function name as the return value, which means you are missing `Set` on the `GetRS()` method in the `classDB` class. Line should be `Set GetRS = RS`.

Comment: Yep now I get an error that its not allowed when closed. As "EDIT" :)

Comment: I think the problem here is you are instantiating the connection inside the class rather than passing it into the class as an argument. When you return the `ADODB.Recordset` the connection is out of scope and hence the recordset is closed. You could keep the connection in the class but you would need to return something that doesn't rely on an active connection like an array for example (`RS.GetRows()`).

Comment: So I should somehow bring it into the method instead of the Class_Initialize?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to pass the `ADODB.Connection` as a parameter on the `GetRS()` method. This kind of negates the point of the class which is why sometimes abstraction like this just causes more problems than they solve.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid arrays..... so name is (3), address is (8) and so on...... readability gone to waste..... its 2022

Comment: Maybe a private function? if that exist in vbscript?

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `Getrows()` due to the flexibility. There are things you can do to make working with arrays a little more friendly, such as assigning constants for columns i.e. `Const field_member_name = 1`.

Comment: "It's 2022". Haha, true. But you're using 1998's platform.

Comment: I know... therefor I'm entitled to print out fields by name

Comment: As I said, the simplest approach is to pass the connection into the function, so it's instantiated inside the context of the page. That way you can still use an `ADODB.Recordset` object.

Comment: How is GetRows() flexible?

Comment: @LasseEdsvik `ADODB.Recordset` as you are finding out is dependent on a database connection whereas `GetRows()` returns a 2D array in memory. `ADODB.Recordset` has varying restrictions like CursorType (Forward-Only etc.), but arrays do not. Also in terms of performance `GetRows()` in my experience outstrips `ADODB.Recordset` for iteration of data.

Comment: But shouldn't it work to return a recordset and loop through it?

Comment: You already have to make a db connection to retrieve the rows...... so I don't see how adding another array and filling it up with data is efficient....... but hey... it was the 1998

Comment: There are various ways to approach this, if you want to use an `ADODB.Recordset` you need to define your connection in the context of the page and then pass it into your class either as an argument to `GetRS()` or have a sub procedure that initially sets the connection object to a private member in the class. The key is the connection is set up inside the page before it is passed to the class.

Comment: Ty all for your comments. I'll look into that tomorrow :) I up-voted your comments. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is due to the lack of `Set` on the returned object reference in the `GetRS()` method in the `classDB` class. The fix for this is to change the return value so it is prefixed with `Set` like this;

```vb
Public Function GetRS(SQL)
    Dim RS: Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)
    'Returning object references from a function requires the "Set" statement.
    Set GetRS = RS
End Function
```

You then reported a "not allowed when closed" error. This comes from the encapsulation of the `ADODB.Connection` object inside the `classDB` object instance. Because the connection is scoped to the class returning a recordset causes the connection to be severed, hence the recordset returning as closed.

The fix is to bring the connection outside the class so it lives in the context of the page and then passes it into the class via a parameter. There are varying ways of doing this, you could add a argument to the `GetRS()` method but this would only affect that single method. The other option is to build a sub procedure that you call after instantiation of the class to set the connection, something like;

```vb
Class classDB
    'Declarations
    Private SQL
    Private RS
    Private Conn

    Public Sub Init(conn)
        Set Conn = conn
    End Sub

    'Terminate Class
    Private Sub Class_Terminate()           
        If IsObject(RS) Then 
            If RS.State = 1 Then
                RS.Close()
            End If
        End If 
        
        If Conn.State = 1 Then
            Conn.Close()
        End If          
    End Sub

    Public Function GetRS(SQL)
        Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)

        GetRS = RS
    End Function


    Public Function ExecuteSQL(SQL)
        Conn.Execute(SQL)
    End Function
End Class
```

You then make sure to call it before using the class and pass your `ADODB.Connection` object.

```vb
'Key is connection object is declared in the scope of the page
Dim conn: Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Call conn.Open("DSN=x")

'GET PAGED MEMBERS
Function GetMembers(page)
    If Not IsNumeric(page) Or page = "" Then page = 1

    Dim db : Set db = new classDB
    'Call init() method and pass connection into the class instance.
    Call db.Init(conn)
    
    Set GetMembers = db.GetRS("SELECT * FROM member")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Will I get problems with Class_Terminate in a similar way (Or I might not even notice it not doing what it should do)?

Comment: No, as the connection is passed into the class via the `Init()` method and then sets the `Conn` private property to that object reference. So the code should still work in the `Class_Terminate` as before. The only time you might get an issue is if the `conn` object reference is manually closed while still using the class.